# Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000ms

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I created this hook:

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

export const GET_DECIDER = gql`
  query GetDecider($name: [String]!) {
    deciders(names: $name) {
      decision
      name
      value
    }
  }
`;

export const useDecider = (name) => {
  const { loading, data } = useQuery(GET_DECIDER, { variables: { name } });
  console.log('loading:', loading);
  console.log('data:', data);
  return { enabled: data?.deciders[0]?.decision, loading };
};
```

Im trying to test it with react testing library:

```
const getMock = (decision) => [
  {
    request: {
      query: GET_DECIDER,
      variables: { name: 'FAKE_DECIDER' },
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        deciders: [{ decision }],
      },
    },
  },
];

const FakeComponent = () => {
  const { enabled, loading } = useDecider('FAKE_DECIDER');

  if (loading) return <div>loading</div>;

  console.log('DEBUG-enabled:', enabled);

  return <div>{enabled ? 'isEnabled' : 'isDisabled'}</div>;
};


// Test 
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen, cleanup, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import { useDecider, GET_DECIDER } from './useDecider';


describe('useDecider', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    cleanup();
  });

  it('when no decider provided - should return false', async () => {
    render(<MockedProvider mocks={getMock(false)}>
             <FakeComponent />
           </MockedProvider>
          );
    expect(screen.getByText('loading')).toBeTruthy();

    act((ms) => new Promise((done) => setTimeout(done, ms)))

    const result = screen.findByText('isDisabled');
    expect(result).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I keep getting this error:

> Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 5000 ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.Error:

Comment: What's `ms` in `act(() => new Promise((done) => setTimeout(done, ms)))`? I don't see it defined anywhere.

Comment: Sorry typo just an argument to the act callback